# Spring Batch - Understanding the behaviour between chunk size and ItemReadListener

Tags: java, spring, iteration, listener, spring-batch

### Situation

I have setup a simple read job in spring batch using java config and I am trying to write a simple listener. The listener should display the amount of time it took in seconds for a certain amount of records to be read.

The bean looks as following:

```
@Bean
public SimpleItemReaderListener listener(){
    SimpleItemReaderListener listener = new SimpleItemReaderListener<>();           
    listener.setLogInterval(50000);
    return listener;
}
```

Based on the set log interval, a message will be displayed and the message will look like this:

```
14:42:11,445  INFO main SimpleItemReaderListener:45 - Read records [0] to [50.000] in average 1,30 seconds
14:42:14,453  INFO main SimpleItemReaderListener:45 - Read records [50.000] to [100.000] in average 2,47 seconds
14:42:15,489  INFO main SimpleItemReaderListener:45 - Read records [100.000] to [150.000] in average 1,03 seconds
14:42:16,448  INFO main SimpleItemReaderListener:45 - Read records [150.000] to [200.000] in average 0,44 seconds
```

Exactly how I want it, perfect. However, when I change the chunk in my batchConfiguration from 100.000 to let's say 1.000, the logging changes and I don't know what is causing the change...

```
14:51:24,893  INFO main SimpleItemReaderListener:45 - Read records [0] to [50.000] in average 0,90 seconds
14:51:50,657  INFO main SimpleItemReaderListener:45 - Read records [50.000] to [100.000] in average 0,57 seconds
14:52:16,392  INFO main SimpleItemReaderListener:45 - Read records [100.000] to [150.000] in average 0,59 seconds
14:52:42,125  INFO main SimpleItemReaderListener:45 - Read records [150.000] to [200.000] in average 0,61 seconds
```

Being under the impression that the beforeRead and afterRead methods in the ItemReaderListener will be executed for each individual item, I was expecting the time it took for each 50.000 to be more in line with the time shown from the slf4j log (e.g. around 26 seconds for each 50.000).

### Question

**What part of my listener is causing this unwanted behaviour when I change the chunk size?**

### Reproduce

My implementation of the ItemReadListener is as following:

```
public class SimpleItemReaderListener<Item> implements ItemReadListener<Item>{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleItemReaderListener.class);
    private static final double NANO_TO_SECOND_DIVIDER_NUMBER = 1_000_000_000.0;    
    private static final String PATTERN = ",###";   

    private int startCount = 0;
    private int logInterval = 50000;
    private int currentCount;
    private int totalCount;
    private long timeElapsed;
    private long startTime;
    private DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(PATTERN);

    @Override
    public void beforeRead() {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();              
    }

    @Override
    public void afterRead(Item item) {
        updateTimeElapsed();        
        if (currentCount == logInterval) {          
            displayMessage();
            updateStartCount();
            resetCount();
        } else {
            increaseCount();
        }       
    }

    private void updateTimeElapsed() {
        timeElapsed += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    }

    private void displayMessage() {
        LOG.info(String.format("Read records [%s] to [%s] in average %.2f seconds", 
                decimalFormat.format(startCount), 
                decimalFormat.format(totalCount), 
                timeElapsed / NANO_TO_SECOND_DIVIDER_NUMBER));      
    }

    private void updateStartCount() {
        startCount += currentCount;
    }

    private void resetCount() {
        currentCount = 0;
        timeElapsed = 0;
    }

    private void increaseCount() {
        currentCount++;
        totalCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadError(Exception arg0) {
        // NO-OP
    }

    public void setLogInterval(int logInterval){
        this.logInterval = logInterval;
    }
}
```

The full batchconfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {   

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")            
                .flow(validateInput())
                .end()
                .build();
    }    

    @Bean
    public Step validateInput() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("validateInput")
                .chunk(1000)
                .reader(reader())               
                .listener(listener())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean 
    public HeaderTokenizer tokenizeHeader(){
        HeaderTokenizer tokenizer = new HeaderTokenizer();
        //optional setting, custom delimiter is set to ','
        //tokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        return tokenizer;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleItemReaderListener listener(){
        SimpleItemReaderListener listener = new SimpleItemReaderListener<>();
        //optional setting, custom logging is set to 1000, increase for less verbose logging
        listener.setLogInterval(50000);
        return listener;
    }

    @Bean   
    public FlatFileItemReader reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader reader = new FlatFileItemReader();        
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);        
        reader.setSkippedLinesCallback(tokenizeHeader());
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("majestic_million.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {{
            setLineTokenizer(tokenizeHeader());
            setFieldSetMapper(new PassThroughFieldSetMapper());
        }});
        return reader;
    }    

    @Bean
    public DummyItemWriter writer(){
        DummyItemWriter writer = new DummyItemWriter();
        return writer;
    }
}
```

Or use the spring boot example from http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/ and add the SimpleItemReaderListener bean.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong things and/or drawing the wrong conclusions. The timestamps are just the timestamps that they are written. If you change the chuck size you will get more commits and thus transactions, starting/stopping transactions is slow, so it will take longer. Also only 1000 will be read and as it will take 50 times instead of 5 times an increase in time should be visible.

Comment: Thanks for this fast respons. Am I correct in understanding you that, when I put the chunk on 1000 and the logInterval on 50.000, I should multiply the timeElapsed by 50 (50.000 / 1000 ) to get a more accurate measurement of the time it took for 50.000 records to be read?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is spending more time outside the reader when the batch size is small. Your timing code only measures time spent in the reader but the logging framework shows timestamps which is time spent total.

Comment: Allright, I do actually only want to display time spent in the reader, so thats good. I will try and adjust my code to reflect time spent total.